# Ckeditor removes content of textarea when the record is edited in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR in my project for user input, which allows HTML input as well. I use this code to initialize CKEDITOR in my project using this code, and works well.

```html
   <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
   </script>
```

The problem is when I edit the same record in edit page, with same initialization script resulting the CKEDITOR does not contain / retain the previous value fetched in the textarea from the database. Each time when the record is edited it loads fresh and new page to input contents.

I need to edit the record / field with CKeditor with previously saved values. Is there any issue with that? This issue has not been detected in TinyMCE editor and it works well even when the record is edited.

Comment: this issue has been resolved. Replace the TextareaFor<> to html <textarea></textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been resolved. Replace the TextareaFor<> to html

```html
   <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
   </script>
```